# Format Date and time into 24 hours format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a app using angularjs.Here is my code:

```
$scope.from = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
```

It shows me output like:`2016-05-15 06:30`
But I want to show like:`2016-05-15 18:30`

Answer (score 23):

Here is the API https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date:

`'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'`

Answer (score 4):

Us it like this  : `$filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');`

check jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4qn9kj5/)

Answer (score 2):

Following formats work :

**Non-Padded:**
If you were to use non padded format like  6:30 or 8:30 then go for **'H'**

```
<div>{{ date_expression | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm'}}</div> <!-- in HTML -->
$filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm'); //in Controller
```

**Padded:**
If you were to use padded format like  06:30 or 08:30 then go for **'HH'**

```
<div>{{ date_expression | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</div> <!-- in HTML -->
$filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'); //in Controller
```

**For Further Reference:**
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date